# Re-attaching hinge to brickwork

Tags: repair, building

What's the best mortar/filler/glue to re-attach an iron hinge into a brick wall?

I have a garden gate hinged onto a brick wall. My guess is the hinge was cemented into the wall when it was built. Picture attached.

[image]

The hinge is very loose (couple of inches play side-to-side). My question is how best to re-attach it? I could mix up some cement, but don't want to buy a bag of cement for a cup-full of mortar, maybe some sort of epoxy resin? or filler? or something else? I hoping for something I can pick up from my local hardware store. I'm in the UK, so my product availability may be different than yours.

Despite it's looseness, the hinge can't be removed completely, but the gate can be lifted off the hinge

Comment: It's _excellent_ that you identified your locale in the UK. The way you phrased it, though, could flag to some people that you're looking for a production recommendation and cause a close vote. I reworded it in an attempt to stave those votes off.

Comment: I like your epoxy idea for this. Most cement products will tend to be brittle and fail under such force. I'll let our resident masons post proper answers.